# jQuery less/more button set in php foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want show post with for-each. My condition is 1st show 5 post and hide other post with a `show more` button if loop has more than 5 post, then when I click show more then will show other post and hide `show more` button and show `less more` button. If post has less then 5 then no showing `show more` button. How can I do that by jQuery?

```
<?php
        foreach ($hotel_data as $key => $hoteldata)
    {
        //Show 3 lowest price of hotel link
        if(isset($hoteldata[0]->rooms)){
            /*$ii = 0;*/
            foreach ($hoteldata[0]->rooms as $key => $bookinginfo) {
                ?> 
                <tr>
                <td class="">
                    <div class="hotel_name">
                        <?php echo $bookinginfo->desc; ?>
                    </div>
                </td>


                <td class="booking-img">
                    <img src="http://pics.avs.io/hl_gates/100/30/<?php echo $bookinginfo->agencyId; ?>.png"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="hotel-price">
                        Price : $ <?php echo $bookinginfo->price; ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="booking-url">
                    <a href="<?php echo $bookinginfo->fullBookingURL; ?>" class="btn btn-info" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $bookinginfo->agencyName; ?>">  BOOK NOW</a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                /*$ii++;
                if($ii > 2){
                    break;
                }*/
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-think your strategy. What you want can be best achieved with AJAX calls. Therefore you need to write your loop with with JS /jQuery. PHP would only handle the retrieval of posts.

For example, you can create an AJAX call that sends a POST request to a PHP script, sending the number of posts you would want. When PHP receives the request, it fetches the posts needed from the DB and sends the results back in JSON format, JS will then parse the results into your HTML.

The AJAX call can be called once at page load (loads first 5), then it can be called again when the "load more" button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Take count of array if more than 5 show "show more" button. Please see example below:

```
<?php
    // Get count
    $count = count($hotel_data);
    foreach ($hotel_data as $key => $hoteldata) {
        //Show 3 lowest price of hotel link
        if(isset($hoteldata[0]->rooms)) {
            /*$ii = 0;*/
            foreach ($hoteldata[0]->rooms as $key => $bookinginfo) {
                ?> 
                <tr>
                    <td class="">
                        <div class="hotel_name">
                            <?php echo $bookinginfo->desc; ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>


                    <td class="booking-img">
                        <img src="http://pics.avs.io/hl_gates/100/30/<?php echo $bookinginfo->agencyId; ?>.png"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="hotel-price">
                            Price : $ <?php echo $bookinginfo->price; ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="booking-url">
                        <a href="<?php echo $bookinginfo->fullBookingURL; ?>" class="btn btn-info" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $bookinginfo->agencyName; ?>">  BOOK NOW</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }

        if ($count>5) {
            // Code for "show more" button
        }
    }
?>
```

Then you have to hide other post by some css class's style property `display: none;`.
For jQuery code, you have to make script on show more button and change property of other posts you have hide. Also change button text to "show less".

Comment: can possible to do that with jQuery?

Comment: Of course, you can do this with jQuery. It's just 5-10 lines of code.

Comment: You should also consider @CodeGodie 's answer to do with AJAX, because it's more proper than show more/less button if you have lots of data to show/hide.